# How many paid Ubuntu developers are there?

Tags: development, canonical

How many paid developers work on developing Ubuntu? How many of them are on Ask Ubuntu?

*When I say "work" I mean they get a monetary reward (salary) for working/participating in the development of it.*

Comment: Do you really think that Just 500 developers can make a gigantic OS who is much better than Windows 8 , Apple ?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

According to their own description, Canonical has over 400 staff and is focussing mainly on Ubuntu. 63% of the Linkedin-using staff is involved in development, so my guess would be something like **250**.

Source for 400 figure: http://www.linkedin.com/company/canonical-ltd.
Source for 63% figure: http://www.linkedin.com/company/canonical-ltd./statistics

Comment: Do you really think that Just 500 developers can make a gigantic OS who is much better than Windows 8 , Apple ?